Video and image load time in flutter and supabase
I am making a social media app using flutter and supabase. I am trying to replicate yt shorts/insta reels into my app but the difference is in the content type, I could be a video, image or audio. The main problem I am facing is the load time. It takes atleast 5-10 secs to load any content which is not good for UX experience. Can anybody guide me through the best method to implement this?
I tried compression but it didn't made a big difference. I have written basic code for video_player and image.network widget. My content is stored in supabase storage.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
